# How to click an input field many times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for my question,but I am not familiar with JavaScript but I need some help.I mostly do programming in **Python** and **C** & **C++**. But for this I need some help from you JavaScript geniuses.
What's the script that will click on an input field once every time the page refreshes? 
So basically there is an input field on a live web page(testing) and I want a script that will generate about 1000 clicks, each click after the page refreshes. How can I do that?
*If you're curious why, it's because I'm testing this mini-web browser that I programmed.* 

Please before you down-vote tell me what's wrong with my question.

Comment: each click page refresh then how do you expect 1000 clicks?

Comment: please refresh your question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="target">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    if(window.location.hash) {
        var hash = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace("#", ""), 10);
        i = hash + 1;
    } 
    if(!window.location.hash || hash < 1000) {
        $('#target').trigger('click');
        window.location.hash = i;
        window.location.reload;
    }
});
```

But why do you want to do this?

Comment: you can run any JS code by just copy pasting in console except onload event once which is like this so you are going to have to edit the page.

Comment: `#target` is the ID for the input field. So essentially we are finding the input field and then clicking on it..